# Nested fragment re-creation happen before parent fragment after ugrading support library to 24.0.0

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently, I have a demo app with the following fragment architecture.

```
MainActivity
    |
    |-- MainFragment
           |
           |-- NestedFragment
```

Here's how I test on fragment re-creation.

### Steps to produce fragment re-creation

- Step 1: Set background process limit to 1

[image]

- Step 2: Launch demo app. We will realize `MainFragment`'s `onCreate` triggered before `NestedFragment`'s `onCreated`
- Step 3: Press home button.
- Step 4: Launch 5 other apps.
- Step 5: Launch demo app again. Fragment re-creation will happen.

Please take note that, step 5 yields different behavior under different support library

---

### com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0

By using the following build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yccheok.demo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

***During step 5, `MainFragment`'s `onCreate` triggered before `NestedFragment`'s `onCreated`***

---

### com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yccheok.demo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

***During step 5, `NestedFragment`'s `onCreate` triggered before `MainFragment`'s `onCreated`***

---

### Code to demonstrate this problem

Can be downloaded from https://github.com/yccheok/demo

I think the behavior of *com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0* is wrong. Isn't child fragment shouldn't be created before parent fragment?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue in my android project. I Am using realm database and for not breaking the db data reference instead of passing the serialized object into the bundle of child fragment am accessing the object in parent fragment through on attach of child fragment. And on recreation since child is recreated first the object from parent that was set in child becomes null.